# 3d vertex.index equivalent in UV 2d

Tags: python, scripting, uv, add-on, vertices

actually I know how to take the 3d and 2d (UV) vertex data.... [I'm using this code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28066/uv-2d-cursor-and-vertex-coordinates-from-python-script-in-edit-mode) with a little modifications

Now I'm trying to find the 3d vertex.index equivalent in UV 2d. that in order to know the uv vertex cordinates of especific 3d vertex index.

I have the same len(3d vertices) and the len(uv 2d vertices), and the 3d vertex only have 1 representation in UV 2d view.

but after run the code I have this:

[image: confused data]

in the example image I have  3d vertex.index #11 selected  and only one UV 2d vertex selected too with his 2d vertex cordinates (366,839)

in order to know that specific cordinates  I have:

```
if ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[v.index].select:
                     print("vertice selected: ", v.index, " cor: ", uv[0]*x, uv[1]*y)
```

but as you see in console I have crazy results

**UPDATE**
I have the same result without UV synch
[image: WITHOUT synch]

UPDATE:
if I select all the verts and in UV editor select 1 point... the result is crazy too...   but I want to know the index relation between 3d vertice index and 2d point index and with this method is imposible: 
[image: WITHOUT SYNCH AND SELECT ALL]
do you have some ideas please?

Comment: disable selection synch and try again ( it seems that UV selection is not  updated while it is active ), you are seeing the previous selection before activating the selection synch option

Comment: @Chebhou thanks for ideas but I have the same result without UV synch, please check the image

Comment: did you reselect again after disabling synch ? you have to select in the UV editor this point to be considered as selected

Comment: @Chebhou, yes, of course... wait....  as you see I can't select that in the UV editor because I can't see that...  but any way I have the same result

Comment: please , select all the verts and you'll see that this point is not selected in the UV

Comment: do you have to do the selection in the 3d view ?

Comment: @Chebhou yes, I have to do the selection in the 3d view because as you see if I disable the UV synch I can´t select that in the UV editor....  ... also if I have the UV sync active, I can select that in the UV editor but nothing change.

also is I select all vertices without UV synch  I can select 1 UV vertice but the result is crazy too.. please check the new update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22975/discussion-between-chebhou-and-yhoyo).

Answer (score 3):

thanks to @Chebhou here the answer:

```
for v in ob.data.vertices : 
            for p in ob.data.loops :

                if v.index == p.vertex_index  and v.select:

                    x = ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[p.index].uv[0]
                    y = ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[p.index].uv[1]

                    print(v.index, " 3d co: ", v.co, " UV co: ", x,",",y)
```